# Trying to access index inside an object

Tags: javascript

I've this piece of code:

```
var state = {}
function init(id) {
    state[id] = {
        house: {
            'test': [
                'hi',
                'hey'
            ]
        },
        car: {
            output: state[id].house['test'][0]
        }
    }
}
init(1);
```

But I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'house')`.

I already tried:

`output: this.state[id].house['test'][0]`
`output: this.house['test'][0]`
`output: house['test'][0]`

And none of them worked. How can I solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assign `state[id].house` later.

```
var state = {}
function init(id) {
    state[id] = {
        house: {
            'test': [
                'hi',
                'hey'
            ]
        },        
    }
    state[id]['car'] = {output: state[id].house['test'][0]}
}
init(1);
```